# How to create a route for testing purposes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, applicationcontroller

I'm writing tests with rspec for my application controller in my rails app (written in Rails 4) and I'm running into a problem where it doesn't recognize the route for the HTTP request I'm sending. I know there's a way to do this using MyApp::Application.routes but I'm not able to get it working.

```
#application_controller_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'


class TestController < ApplicationController

  def index; end

end

describe TestController do
  before(:each) do
    @first_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user) 
      # this is to ensure that all before_filters are run
    controller.stub(:first_time_user)
    controller.stub(:current_user)
end

describe 'first_time_user' do
  before(:each) do
    controller.unstub(:first_time_user)
  end

  context 'is in db' do
    before(:each) do
      @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(@user)
    end

    it 'should not redirect' do
      get :index
      response.should_not be_redirect
    end
  end

  context 'is not in db' do

    context 'session[:cas_user] does not exist' do
      it 'should return nil' do
        get :index
        expect(assigns(:current_user)).to eq(nil)
      end
    end

    it "should redirect_to new_user_path" do
      controller.stub(:current_user, redirect: true).and_return(nil)
      get :index
      response.should be_redirect
    end
  end
end
```

The error I'm getting right now is

```
No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"test"}
```

I would add the test#index route to config/routes.rb, but it doesn't recognize the Test Controller, so I want to do something like

```
MyApp::Application.routes.append do
  controller :test do
    get 'test/index' => :index
  end
end
```

but I'm not sure where to add this or if this even works in rspec. Any help would be great!

Comment: How do you mean: "I would add the test#index route to config/routes.rb, but it doesn't recognize the Test Controller" ??  Add the route to routes.rb and do a "rake routes" from the terminal and check the output. Could be an issue with singular/plural and the generation of the controller name.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear-- when I rake routes, it throw "rake aborted! missing :controller" The problem is the Test Controller only exists in the file "application_controller_spec.rb"

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to test your ApplicationController, see this [RSpec documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-14/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller) about it. You will need to define methods like `index` inside the test, but it works well.